# How to connect to API and load the data directly in Snowflake table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I was wondering if `Snowflake` can directly connect to API and load the data into Snowflake Schema tables ? If yes, can you please guide me the process ? I am new to `Snowflake` please provide example along with explanation.

Thanks in advance for your time and efforts!

Comment: You’ll find that the Snowflake documentation is a good place to start

Comment: Can you please point me to that documentation ?

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/index.html

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of Snowflake external functions calling an API and loading the returned data set [How Snowflake’s IT team uses external functions](https://medium.com/snowflake/how-snowflakes-it-team-uses-external-functions-497505fb49df#:%7E:text=One%20Snowflake%20feature%20that%20is%20particularly%20useful%20for,cloud%20serverless%20compute%20services%20such%20as%20AWS%20Lambda.).

Answer (score -1):

With new snowflake external network integration you can now load data directly from api using snowflake snowpark and secrets and network integration as of Oct 2023 .

Use python request module and snowflake network, snowflake secrets and create a UDF . I have a sample will share / update this post once I have it .
Other wise use this example : https://harke-harkema.medium.com/new-in-snowflake-external-network-access-f035cbe56bf8